# Logstash 7.10.2 Windows x64 - How to add Memorize plugin into it

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok, elk

I am having logstash-filter-memorize.gemspec file. I don't know how to add this memorize plugin into logstash. Can someone please help me how to add this plugin into logstash in windows 10 operating system.

Comment: the memorize plugin does not work anymore since version 6